# Missing option to silence text conversation in iOS 11

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

Last night I wanted to silence a text conversation and didn’t see the option. Is that gone, too? iPhone 6s after iOS 11 upgrade

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/8-great-new-messages-features-ios-11-for-iphone-0178019/):

> iOS 11 renamed the "Do Not Disturb" option for conversation threads to "Hide Alerts," and the toggle is still accessible by hitting the information icon in the top right. But that's too many steps for some of us, so Apple added a shortcut to the swipe menu on the Messages homepage which quickly disables notifications for both individual and group chats whenever they get out of control. Just swipe left on any message thread to access the new "Hide Alert" shortcut.
>
> The latter method is especially handy, as it can disable notifications from outside the conversation itself and prevents the "Read" receipt from being triggered, giving us plausible deniability with regards to reading any messages.

[image]
[image]